# What's the busiest airport that's not WGS-84 compliant?

Tags: navigation, gnss, navaids

Most latitude and longitude coordinates are defined relative to the WGS-84 standard, including GPS coordinates from your receiver.  However, some coordinates are specified using local datums, and these datums are often imprecise enough that even if you did convert them to the same datum as your GPS receiver, your receiver would be over a hundred feet off. (Code 7700 has [more information](http://code7700.com/wgs-84.htm) on the issue).

Some examples can be found through [Jeppesen](https://ww2.jeppesen.com/wgs-84-status/) and [Garmin](https://avdb.garmin.com/docs/garmin_data_exclusions.html), like some of the SIDs around WIII and approaches at FLKK.  I don't have firsthand experience with any non-compliant navaids personally though so it's hard to tell how big a problem this really is.

Nowadays most (95%+) of navaids and airports are compliant.  I've heard even all international Russian airports are now compliant.  So what's the busiest airport with non-standard coordinates?

Comment: Can you give us an example of at least one airport - presumably not very busy - that isn't WGS-84 compliant? That might help to clarify what you're asking.

Comment: @Pondlife, just follow the link. Apparently such problems are real, though really strange to me, since they say “Although the fidelity of their methods are not in question, the simple fact that using different methods exposes the possibility that position information may not match when compared to WGS-84 methods.”, but if the fidelity was there, matching the coordinate systems and converting between them might be tedious, but still possible and reliable.